# find first and last value for unique julian date

Tags: matlab

i have a data set similar to the following:

```
bthd = sort(floor(1+(10-1).*rand(10,1)));
bthd2 = sort(floor(1+(10-1).*rand(10,1)));
bthd3 = sort(floor(1+(10-1).*rand(10,1)));

Depth = [bthd;bthd2;bthd3];
Jday = [repmat(733774,10,1);repmat(733775,10,1);repmat(733776,10,1)];

temp = 10+(30-10).*rand(30,1);

Data = [Jday,Depth,temp];
```

where I have a matrix similar to 'Data' with Julian Date in the first column, depth in the second, and then temperature in the third column. I would like to find what are the first and last values are for each unique Jday. This can be obtained by:

```
Data = [Jday,Depth,temp];

[~,~,b] = unique(Data(:,1),'rows');

for j = 1:length(unique(b));
    top_temp(j) = temp(find(b == j,1,'first'));
    bottom_temp(j) = temp(find(b == j,1,'last'));
end
```

However, my data set is extremely large and using this loop results in long running time. Can anyone suggest a vectorized solution to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html):

```
% for example
Jday = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 6 7 7 7];
last = find( [diff(Jday) 1] );
first = [1 last(1:end-1)+1];
top_temp = temp(first) ;
bottom_temp = temp(last);
```

Note that this solution assumes `Jday` is sorted. If this is not the case, you may `sort` `Jday` prior to the suggested procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish this using the occurrence option of the `unique` function:

```
[~, topidx, ~] = unique(Data(:, 1), 'first', 'legacy');
[~, bottomidx, ~] = unique(Data(:, 1), 'last', 'legacy');

top_temp = temp(topidx);
bottom_temp = temp(bottomidx);
```

The legacy option is needed if you're using MATLAB R2013a. You should be able to remove it if you're running R2012b or earlier.

Comment: isn't it a bit redundant to use `unique` twice? Especially if `Jday` is already sorted...

Comment: @Shai Good point. Your solution is definitely the better one, but I felt it was worth noting that `unique` could do exactly what was requested.